# RESTful service errors out when POST array is *not* empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to cURL in to my first real attempt at a RESTful service.
(I'm using the codeigniter-restserver library that @Phil-Sturgeon put together.)

The service works great with GET requests.
POST, on the other hand, is throwing me a curve ball. Attempts with an **empty** POST array are successful ... all others seem to fail.

**CODE:**

```
/*** sandbox  ***/
...
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/project/api/companies');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// This works.
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array());

// This throws the error
//curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('chicken'=>'licken'));

$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
var_export($buffer);
...


/*** RESTful controller ***/
...
function companies_post(){
    $this->response('It Works!', 200);
}  // end method: companies_post()
...
```

**ERROR:**
When my `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` array is anything *other than* empty, I get:

> An Error Was Encountered
>   The action you have requested is not allowed.

**GOAL:**
My *immediate goal* is to simply return the POST payload in the response just so I can prove the round-trip is working.
At this point, though, I'd settle for simply being able to POST *anything* of substance to the API without throwing an error :)

Anyone ever hear of anything like that?
What am I missing here?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your error.  All of your code works.  However, I did run into an interesting problem with posting to a file that makes a curl request to itself ( i ran apache out of connections).  Anyway, I think your problem is not with curl.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Seth. My suspicion is that the problem is in @philsturgeons library ... or more accurately, my implementation/configuration of it ;). I was REALLY hoping that I was just making some simple bone-head mistake ... it's easy to un-bone those :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think CSRF protection is set to `TRUE` in config file for the REST application. You either need to pass the CSRF token name and CSRF hash as its value in your curl POST request array OR turn it off by changing its value to `FALSE`

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: You win. Didn't see this when I posted mine, must have had the link open overnight.

Comment: Perfect. This did it. Thanks for the additional info about how to pass the CSRF cred's. I'll have to try that too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable the csrf only for the api requests.
Example: Edit the config.php and change the $config['csrf_protection'] line to

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) 
      && stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/api') !== FALSE) {
  $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is a bitch. Turn it off:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

In later versions you can add whitelist IPs/domains, which your client will be one of them.